# How to color character linux terminal

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

I would like your your help writing some code:
I would like Ubuntu 12.04.1 Terminal to color "/" character opposite as other text.

This could be very important for pretty much everyone, who writes bash/python directly in console...

**Any ideas where to start?**

I'm thinking of a custom plugin fo terminal, that could parse text right before it is printed?

Answer (score 0):

The `tput` command is your friend (assuming you want to stay in shell-script land).

```
$ tput smso; echo Bold text; tput rmso
```

Q: What will highlighting */* characters give you?

Comment: I want it to do it all the time every time after reboot too :)

Comment: The point of this is to ease the reading of code and/or unix paths in terminal. For example, imagine how readable "cd /var/cpdb/pdb/php/pdb/php.php" becomes after all "/" get colored red or opposite color.